# invalid column name when my insert data is string,when i use int it works fine

Tags: c#-4.0

When i replace `EmerPacienti` with `PatientId` it works fine, why happen that?

```
if (DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value == "In-Pacient")
{
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Ipacient where EmerPacienti=" + TextBox11.Text + "", cn);
    //SqlCommandBuilder Cmd = new SqlCommandBuilder(Da);
    DataSet Ds = new DataSet();
    Da.Fill(Ds, "Ipacient");
    GridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: You should add single qoutes 
select * from Ipacient where EmerPacienti='" + TextBox11.Text + "'" 
pay attention to the single quotes between the double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sql parameters to prevent sql injection, then you also don't need to wrap it in apostrophes which is required on text columns. So this is much better:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("insert connection string"))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Ipacient where EmerPacienti=@EmerPacienti", cn))
{
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EmerPacienti", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table);
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

If it was an `int`-value use `int.Parse`/`int.TryParse`:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("insert connection string"))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Ipacient where PatientId=@PatientId", cn))
{
    int patientId;
    if (int.TryParse(TextBox11.Text, out patientId))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = patientId;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You,it was very productive answer :)